# When Use FileChannel to read()/write() files?

Tags: java, nio, java-io

I am reading the book *Thinking in Java,* which explains the `java.nio.*` package and says that NIO is faster than reading and writing files with traditional IO streams. Why?

I have reviewed the following information:

- IO stream is byte oriented, traditional IO processing unit is byte, and NIO processing unit is block (byte array), but I think traditional IO can also directly process block (byte array) through BufferedFile*, and traditional IO also has direct Method of processing byte array

  ```
  private native int readBytes(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException;
  ```
- IO is blocking read, NIO can be non-blocking, but I found that the file NIO can only be non-blocking, then NIO has no advantage.
- I think the need to use NIO is generally other advantages that need to use NIO, such as:

  ```
   transferTo()/transferFrom()
  ```

So, when should I use NIO for file reading and writing? Why is it faster than traditional IO? What is the correct way to use it? Should I use IO or NIO only when reading and writing files?

Comment: Private methods are not part of the API. 'Not useful' does not follow from the lack of non-blocking mode. Does the book really say 'faster'? or 'can be faster'? or 'more scaleable'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are only two cases where a `FileChannel` is faster than a `FileInputStream` or `FileOutputStream`.

The first is when you can use an off-heap ("direct") `ByteBuffer` to hold data, so that it isn't copied into the Java heap. For example, if you were writing a web-server that delivered static files to a socket, it would be faster to use a `FileInputStream` and a `SocketChannel` rather than a `FileInputStream` and a `SocketOutputStream`.

These cases are, in my opinion, very few and far between. Normally when you read (or write) a file in Java you will be doing something with the data. In which case, you can't avoid copying the data onto the heap.

The other use for a `FileChannel` is to create a `MappedByteBuffer` for random access to the contents of a file. This is significantly faster than using `RandomAccessFile` because it replaces explicit calls to the OS kernel with memory accesses that leverage the OS's paging mechanism.

If you're just getting started with I/O in Java, I recommend sticking with the classes in `java.io` unless and until you can explain why switching to `java.nio` will give you improved performance. It's much easier to use a stream-oriented abstraction than a block-oriented one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also very much agree with your point of view. It seems that I should understand the meaning of the wrong book.